# structure "had it been.." vs "was it.."

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

I am still confused about the "had it not been" structure after reading so many related threads.

When describing, say Elon Musk, about his drive and passion (which he has been having), which of the following sounds right?

> A. Had it not been the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he
>   would not have been so dedicated.
>
> B. Was it not the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he
>   would not be so dedicated.
>
> C. If it had not been the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he
>   would not have been so dedicated.
>
> D. If it was not the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he
>   would not be so dedicated.

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  This site is not intended to help answer quiz (or homework) questions.  Please share what research you have already done, and what you found that confused you.  What do you think the answer might be?  (To improve your question, use the **[Edit]** button on your question and add details, please.)  Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A. Had it not been **for** the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he would not have been so dedicated.

This is fine.

It's placing everything very much in the past tense, while the project to colonize Mars is ongoing and current. So, that's a small problem regarding meaning, but not grammar.  Are you recounting the story of when he founded SpaceX, and only that part? Then perhaps the past tense is ok.

> B. Was it not the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he would not be so dedicated.

"Was" should be "were", which isn't plural here, but rather the subjunctive form. "For" should be added.

> B2. **Were** it not **for** the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he would not be so dedicated.

> C. If it had not been **for** the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he would not have been so dedicated.

This is fine.

> D. If it was not the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he would not be so dedicated.

"Was" should be "were", which is the conditional form. "For" should be added.

> D2. If it **were** not **for** the strong desire to help humanity colonize mars, he would not be so dedicated.

In summary, any of the above four variations could be used.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, @Sam. So meaning wise, what if I want to make it current instead of recounting the story in the past? What would you say?

Comment: @learningc B and D are in the present tense - "he would not be so dedicated".